# setRowData not loading the data in to the grid

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid to display the values in to the grid.But with using setRowData is not loading the values in to the grid.Below is my code where i am calling setRowData in setTimeOut function as it it throwing api is undefined:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body ng-app ng-controller="CustController as custCtrl">
     <div ag-grid="custCtrl.gridOptions" id="myGrid" style="height: 
      115px;width:500px;" class="ag-fresh"></div>
 </body>
</html>

var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.controller('CustController', function($scope, $http) {
var columnDefs = [
  {headerName: "Customer Name", field: "custName"},
  {headerName: "Address", field: "address"},
  {headerName: "Ph NO", field: "phNo"}
];

var rowData = [
{custName: "A", address: "xyz", phNo: '123-123-1234'},
{custName: "B", address: "lmn", phNo: '345-456-5672'},
{custName: "C", address: "pqr", phNo: '903-456-2345'}
];

var gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  enableColResize: true,
  rowBuffer:0,
  enableSorting: true,
  enableFilter: true,
  rowHeight: 30,
  headerHeight: 35,
  sizeColumnsToFit: true,
  onGridReady: function () {
    setTimeout( function(){
                        $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(rowData);
                    },5000);
   },
   suppressLoadingOverlay: true,
   pagination: true
 };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the onGridReady function outside of the gridOptions.

```
var rowData = [
{custName: "A", address: "xyz", phNo: '123-123-1234'},
{custName: "B", address: "lmn", phNo: '345-456-5672'},
{custName: "C", address: "pqr", phNo: '903-456-2345'}
];
```

From database via a http get method on click of button calling getData() function

```
$scope.getData = function(){
  //console.log("hello");
  $http.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-docs/master/src/olympicWinners.json")
    .then(function(res){
        $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(res.data);
    });
}
```

> https://plnkr.co/edit/PKTiFpd9WM1UeELT72ht?p=preview

Comment: Hi koolhuman it didnot work.Do i need to change the data to array as i read that setRowData accepts only array.

Comment: your rowdata is already an array -

var rowData = [
{custName: "A", address: "xyz", phNo: '123-123-1234'},
{custName: "B", address: "lmn", phNo: '345-456-5672'},
{custName: "C", address: "pqr", phNo: '903-456-2345'}
];

i have added a link to the answer

Comment: Hi koolhuman thanks it worked.Now when i am trying to load the values from the database i dont see ag-grid is populating the data.

Comment: @GrailsLearner - how are you populating the data from database? I have updated the answer to fetch from database.

Comment: function getData(){
        
        MF3HTTPService.get('personallink').then(function(data){
            if(data.status >= 200 && data.status < 300){
                if(!angular.isnull(data) && !angular.isnull(data.data)){                    
         vm.rowData=data.data;
                        
                        console.log("Data Found:"+JSON.stringify(vm.rowData));
}
                }       
        });
}

Comment: in the vm.rowData i am able to see my data from the database but not able to bind the data to the grid by the below code:onGridReady(params) {
    params.api.setRowData(vm.rowData);
}

Comment: @GrailsLearner please update your code in the question or put it in plnker else it is difficult to debug the issue

Comment: @GrailsLearner your jsfiddle has console errors - angular is not defined.

Comment: refer to this link - https://plnkr.co/edit/PKTiFpd9WM1UeELT72ht?p=preview

Comment: @GrailsLearner - Glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

Your gridOptions variable is not defined on your $scope, yet you are trying to access it via the scope in the onGridReady function.

Try this:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  enableColResize: true,
  rowBuffer:0,
  enableSorting: true,
  enableFilter: true,
  rowHeight: 30,
  headerHeight: 35,
  sizeColumnsToFit: true,
  onGridReady: function () {
    setTimeout( function(){
                        $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(rowData);
                    },5000);
   },
   suppressLoadingOverlay: true,
   pagination: true
 };
});
```